# Spinner which always shows "x selected"

Tags: android-actionbar, spinner, selection

I am struggeling now for a few hours to get a selection spinner like the picture below.
How can I achieve this, to get a spinner which always shows "x selected" and not the current selection.

Thanks for your help.

[image: Android Developer Design ActionBar]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i finally made it.

I write my own Adapter which overrides the getView(...)-Method and returns a TextView.

```
public class SelectionSpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>{

    Context context;

    public SelectionSpinnerAdapter(Context context, int resource, CharSequence[] objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(context, null, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        textView.setText("Your Text");
        return textView;
    }

}
```